# How to execute multiple statement in one line in mysql and get result into dataset

Tags: c#, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm developing an windows application using `MySQL` as `data-base server`.
I need to execute a prepared statement and want to load result into data-set without using `stored procedure`.
Can any one tell me how can i do this.

### Statement

```
 SET @Statment =
  (
    SELECT REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                        GROUP_CONCAT(
                                      Concat(' SELECT COUNT(*) AS `ROWS`//''',TABLE_NAME,''' AS `TABLE` FROM ', TABLE_NAME , ' UNION ALL')
                                    )
                         ,',','')
                 ,'//',',')
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wbss'
  );
  SET @Statment = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@Statment,1,LENGTH(@Statment) - 9));
  PREPARE STMT FROM @Statment;
  EXECUTE STMT;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
```

Note:- I'm not having permission to do this using stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing these queries as a parameter for MYSql command?try concatenating them and passing as single string. try with hard coded values to begin with.
I don't want to tell you the exact solution but may be something like this:

`cmd.CommandText = "insert into animals (id, name) values (:id, :name);+
    select id, name from animals where id = last_insert_id()";`

Please do not consider it a literal solution.Consider it an option and make your way through it.

Comment: Not working.But if we split hole statement and loop through each statement in same command then it works.But is there any way to do this in a single line like SQL Server.

Comment: please elaborate what are you facing.

Comment: It troughs error.Error message:- `ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.33-community]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @Statment = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@Statment,1,LENGTH(@Statment) - 9));
  PREPAR' at line 12`

Comment: Since you are using parameterized query,why do not you do the sub string on statement in code and store it in a string and then use the string in your query?